# How to remove all traces of an old GitHub repo in Visual Studio Code? ("A Git repository was found that was previously closed)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, version-control

I have a project in Visual Studio Code. I had initially created a GitHub repo for it online. For various reasons I decided to delete the online repo and start over. I also deleted the local .git folder on my drive.

Now I would like to create a new repo from inside Visual Studio Code.

1. I restart VS Code.
2. I select my project folder.
3. I click on the SCM icon.

I keep on getting the following message: **"A Git repository was found that was previously closed"**. The only offered option is **"Reopen Closed Repository"** - I cannot create or point at a new repo.

[image]

Any idea as to how I can erase all history of this old repo inside VS Code?
And then eventually create or associate this existing local project in VS Code to a new GitHub repo?

Thanks.

Comment: what did you name your new GitHub repo? did you already clone your new github repo? did you close the old repo in VS Code? what happens when you click "reopen"?

Comment: I have not created any new repo yet.
Not sure I closed the old repo in VS Code: I just deleted the local .git folder, deleted the online repo and restarted VS Code...
(I have not tried to click on "reopen" yet)

Comment: try clicking it.

Comment: If I click on "reopen" it prompts me to accept the old repo. Clearly the location of this old repo is saved somewhere in VS Code (it's no longer on disk). 

I looked at various threads but cannot find how to clear that info in VS Code. Any idea where this might live? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [same directory as user settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations), go to `workspaceStorage/`, find the subdirectory there that is for your workspace, and delete the directory.

This is a bit of a lazy and nuclear option. It will remove all memory of everything VS Code remembers about that workspace (except of course, the actual contents of the workspace). There's probably a better and more precise/surgical way, but I'm too lazy to look for it.

Comment: My workspace was remembering a git repository that wasn't in the same folder I had opened.  The clone existed but wasn't the one I was working with, and it wasn't letting me initialize a new one.   I think the concept of a project in Code is just so lax that the folder you open doesn't have to be the folder you're working with.  If there's a "right way" to do this in the UI, it's definitely not apparent.